# RegisterHotkey returns 1 for MOD_CONTROL and VK_SCROLL, but WM_HOTKEY not fired?

Tags: windows, registerhotkey

Per the title... I'm using RegisterHotkey with MOD_CONTROL as the modifier and VK_SCROLL for the key, and the API returns 1 for success, but WM_HOTKEY isn't fired when I press those keys?

WM_HOTKEY fires if I substitute MOD_ALT instead for MOD_CONTROL, so I know my code works. It just doesn't seem to like MOD_CONTROL with VK_SCROLL? Is this maybe a banned key combo for hotkeys? Thanks.

Comment: Recall that Ctrl+Scroll is an alias for Break.

Comment: Ah, okay. But I'm still confused: I can use RegisterHotKey with VK_PAUSE (for Break) and it fires WM_HOTKEY when Pause/Break is pressed, so if Ctrl+Scroll is an alias to it, why doesn't it also fire?

Comment: Maybe it is represented by the keyboard as Ctrl+Break? Keyboard aliases are really weird because the keyboard is trying to synthesize a key that you never pressed.

Comment: I think I'll just make Ctrl+Scroll not selectable in my app as a hotkey option, then, and ignore the return value of 1 that RegisterHotkey is giving for it. BTW, love your blog (been a long-time reader). :)